# Why does my Windows computer immediately turn back on after sleep/hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

After clicking sleep or hibernate in Windows 7, my computer loads for a while and then goes into sleep mode, but not 1 second later it powers back up. The event log has no errors and no warnings appear when it comes back out of sleep/hibernation.

Here's my system specifications:

- [Asus P5KPL-VM](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=i5ktecSJbqQKaa0x)
- Windows 7

I believe this is all that's relevant. I've installed the latest chipset drivers, but I'm unable to update my BIOS (but this is another matter; maybe because the motherboard in the [V3-P5G31 bundle](http://uk.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=B3H6QcghxwvduwI1) is different).

I've also tried turning off the "Allow this device to wake up my computer" for the network card, keyboard, and mouse -- but this makes no difference.

If flashing the BIOS is the only thing that will fix this, then I will create a new question to this effect.

Maybe I should change the suspend mode from S3 to S1?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To continue from [Nicholaz's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/113801/why-does-my-windows-computer-immediately-turn-back-on-after-sleep-hibernate/113859#113859) this reveals some wake events in the event log that I missed out, since they were not errors:

---

To find out what caused your computer to wake from sleep, do the following:

Open Event Viewer by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Event Viewer.‌   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

1. Expand Windows Logs, and then click System.
2. In the Actions pane, click Filter Current Log.
3. In the Filter Current Log dialog box, in the Logged list, select the time range.
4. In the Event sources list, select Power-Troubleshooter, and then click OK.
5. In Event Viewer, in the System pane, select the date and time for the event that you want to view.
6. On the General tab, view the Wake Source for the event.

---

After inspecting the filtered results, I see plenty of messages like so:

```
The system has resumed from sleep.

Sleep Time: ‎2010‎-‎02‎-‎24T23:42:44.283678200Z
Wake Time: ‎2010‎-‎02‎-‎24T23:43:10.233041900Z

Wake Source: Device -USB Root Hub
```

However, I've also spotted this rather annoying "unknown source" variant:

```
The system has resumed from sleep.

Sleep Time: ‎2010‎-‎02‎-‎20T22:41:30.687040200Z
Wake Time: ‎2010‎-‎02‎-‎21T10:07:54.488171000Z

Wake Source: Unknown
```

I will update my answer if the solution is disallowing this device to wake the computer.

### Update:

I have resolved my issue!

Turns out that the "USB Root Hub" source is a little misleading; it was actually *both* my keyboard and mouse that were waking up my computer (without being touched/pressed). The solution was to uncheck "Allow this device to wake up the computer" on both the mouse and keyboard devices (selecting them independently does not resolve the issue).

Perhaps updating my mouse/keyboard drivers will fully resolve the issue.

Comment: Ahh cool, great to hear the link had been helpful (hint hint :-))

Comment: Haha, accepted ;) -- also, updating my Logitech drivers did not "fix" the issue. Stupid bug. Oh well.

Comment: It fix the issues on Windows 8 (and 8.1) too.

Comment: If you disallow mouse and keyboard to "wake from sleep", how do you wake the computher after it goes into sleep? (or am I misreading something?)

Comment: @KevinFegan: Power button.

Comment: This saved me, got the same problem windows starting after 1sec sleep... disabling keyboard and mouse wake solved it. finally i can use WOL!

Comment: This is rather annoying. Why is the source is unknown when the mouse/keyboard woke the system up? I'm facing a similar issue, and about to try this out.

Comment: Unchecking "Allow this device to wake up the computer" for all keyboard devices fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 23):

I had this exact same problem on the exact same motherboard.  But in my case it was just the mouse doing it; the keyboard couldn't wake it up if its life depended on it (and I have it set to do it, too).  Probably because I'm using a PS/2 keyboard, not a USB one, and the auto-wake-up seems connected to USB hub weirdness.  Or something.

I think I'm going to look for a BIOS upgrade now.

At another article, I saw two great commands to run in command prompt that will give more specific answers:

```
powercfg -lastwake
```

and

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
```

Comment: and after you've found out the name of the device just powercfg -devicedisablewake <device_name> to stop it from doing it (require admin)

Comment: I made a program for this purpose. Requires .Net (included since Vista).
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/260388200/Disarm-Wake-Timers.rar
VirusTotal Scan (only one random av picks this as a malware prob. bcause of the necessary UAC permission): https://www.virustotal.com/it/file/eae8564c72fbdd8492523eec6e49ff5f1adc7c364ea7749cad837924ec499187/analysis/1454381129/

Comment: Thanks @flagg19; super helpful! Note: it seems to require double quotes around the device name, like this: `powercfg -devicedisablewake "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V"`

Comment: Simple powershell to disable all(run as adm): `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed | % { powercfg -devicedisablewake $_ }`

Comment: `lastwake` and `devicequery` were not useful in my case, I was only able to find the actual source with `powercfg -requests` which then lead me to this solution: https://superuser.com/a/370571/149000

Answer (score 5):

My Windows PC was having the exact same problem. Turned out to be I had a USB phone charging cord hanging out of one of the PC USB ports with nothing attached. Removing the cord and only using it when I needed to solved the problem.

Comment: Weird! That should not happen. ಠ_ಠ Was it a special, proprietary cord or a generic cord that could be used with any phone? (Not that I expect and answer from Jim, but you never know.)

Answer (score 5):

For future use:
Waking up can also be done by "Wake Timers". To disable those, follow this instructions:

> **Simple fix**
>
> 1.Search for power plan.
>
> 2.Click on power plan
>
> 3.Select advanced settings
>
> 4.Expand sleep section
>
> 5.Expand allow wake timers.
>
> 6.Disable both of them.
>
> **Complex fix**
>
> 1.Search for task scheduler.
>
> 2.Go through each task checking the Conditions.
>
> 3.If you see "Wake the computer to run this task" ticked then untick it (need to right > click on task and select properties).

Credit goes to *monkeymiles*, original url: [Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/163279-pc-reboots-after-going-into-hibernate-mode.html#post1975703)

Answer (score 4):

My answer was a different one: The Samsung Magician application.

I used the answers here to look in the log, and mine was "unknown" which obviously didn't help much.  I disabled devices, etc., nothing worked.

And then I ran across "[Windows 8 wakes up IMMEDIATELY from sleep](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/243c6e42-6b13-489b-89db-002a9bd27148/windows-8-wakes-up-immediately-from-sleep)" over on Windows 8.1 IT Pro forums.  And so I did the same and stopped running Magician.  And my problem was solved.  Sleep works fine.

So if all else fails, and you have a Samsung SSD, disable the magician application.

Answer (score 3):

I have both a "gaming" mouse and keyboard from Logitech. Both come with extra buttons and keys which can be programmed. As a result of its additional functionality, my mouse shows up with devices both under the mouse and keyboard headings in the device manager.

I was able to configure my PC so that only my keyboard would wake the PC. The only way to do this however is by figuring out which HID Keyboard devices were related to my mouse through trial and error. Basically, I unchecked "Allow this device to wake the computer" on one of the devices, put the computer to sleep, and then moved the mouse. If the PC woke up, I tried unchecking the box on one of the other "HID Keyboard Device" entries. Eventually I determined which entry was related to my mouse, and then I rechecked the box on all of the other devices.

Answer (score 1):

You may benefit from updating your BIOS if it's not the newest version already, and/or mucking around with the BIOS settings that wake the machine up. I think you can turn off USB standby power and so on with various mainboards.

You may find that the intent of an option in poorly-documented BIOS interfaces is slightly different than the results it produces - for example, on an early build of the P8Z68-V Pro EFI image (BIOS replacement) if you turn off USB legacy keyboard and mouse support... they stop working in the EFI interface. The mainboard has no PS/2 ports. At this point there is only one way to re-enable them - clear all the settings to default with the reset button.

Fortunately the newer revisions fixed this because it was driving me loopy (the legacy USB keyboard support didn't work properly either, I couldn't use the Intel SSD firmware update CD).

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. I also had the same problem, and the answer is because of your power settings.

Most people set it to high perfomance which doesn't let it enter sleep. Just see *[Troubleshoot power problems](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-power-problems)* and download a small file. It'll fix it for sure; I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Don't forget to disable `wake up on Magic Packet & Wake on Pattern Match (WoL)` or equivalent for the NIC(s) to avoid unexpected wake.

### Story

Recently installed Dell OEM Windows 7 Pro on an Optiplex 990 (to replace a dead Optiplex 790) as the only Windows machine at home. Last time I installed Windows was more than 4 years ago, completely forgot how I got the desktop PC sleep working.

I followed through the process when troubleshooting (`eventvwr.msc` is good), ruled out the unaware wake source one by one:

- USB Keyboard (of course)
- Bluetooth mouse
- USB Root Hub (Generic USB Hub as well)

Windows 7 still wake up within 30s every time after being put to sleep. Event Viewer power-troubleshooter log indicated wake source `Unknown`.

```bsh
The system has resumed from sleep.

Sleep Time: ‎2020‎-‎06‎-‎27T14:16:53.516538400Z
Wake Time: ‎2020‎-‎06‎-‎27T14:17:18.813018000Z

Wake Source: Unknown
```

Confused...

Then a routine operation - used pi-hole (running on a Original Pi 1) to wake up my N54L NAS (`etherwake`) reminded me that the Intel GbE NIC has power saving and WoL options, disabling all non-sense fixed the problem.

### Solution

Key options (don't know which exactly fixed it though):

Power saving options (disable):

- Energy Efficient Ethernet
- Reduce link speed during system idle
- Reduce link speed to save power (WTH...)

WOL

- Wake on Magic Packet (if WoL using Magic Packet from sleep is NOT required)
- Wake on Pattern Matching (most likely this one, nonsense option for Desktop PC)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I was able to solve it. I removed the power adapter from the UPS power supply on to a separate outlet.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, it persisted even when I unplugged everything except the power cord. Restarting the computer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem caused by a PS/2 mouse. Although it was set to `-DEVICEDISABLEWAKE` my BIOS did not respect this setting and would wake the PC anyway if the mouse moved. Replacing it with a USB mouse resolved it.