# Immediately after hibernate the computer starts again

Tags: windows-7

I did [this](https://superuser.com/questions/113801/why-does-my-windows-computer-immediately-turn-back-on-after-sleep-hibernate) - no help

My event log is

```
The system has resumed from sleep.

Sleep Time: ‎...
Wake Time: ‎...

Wake Source: Unknown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution - It was the modem so was awakening the computer!

The best thing to do is - disable the option to wake the computer in ALL devices - then enable what you want.