# Windows 10 won't sleep or turn off after being on for a few hours

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

BEFORE MARKING IT AS DUPLICATE:
Here's what I've tried:

- Updating video drivers: GeForce GT 740M up to date
- Updating network drivers: Realtek PCIe up to date
- NEW: Updating chipset drivers: They were already up to date
- Updating BIOS: Updated to A10
- Turning off hybrid-sleep
- turning off hibernation completely
- Disabling wake timers on all energy plans
- Turning off waking on magic packet/pattern match
- Unplugging all USB and Bluetooth devices
- Setting the sleep idle timer for something else than "never"
- Disabling waking up devices shown in `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`
- Some other things that I don't remember now. Please ask in the comments before marking as duplicate.

If I turn on my computer and open all my applications, I can put my computer to sleep with no problem, but after some hours of it being on, if I try to put it to sleep, it will turn off the screen, but it will not sleep, and the only way to use the computer again is to force a restart by holding down the power button.

This started to happen after I switched my old HD to an SSD and reinstaled windows 10.

**EDIT 1**: Tried shutting Chrome off and running `powercfg -requestsoverride Driver "Legacy Kernel Caller" System` without success

**EDIT 2**:

- When I manually put my machine to sleep, after letting it on after 2+ hours, the screen will turn off, but the power light and the wifi light will stay on, and then I need to forcefully turn the computer off by holding the power button.
- The `powercfg -requests` command was showing the following result:

  > [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
  >   WebRTC has active PeerConnections

...But after killing chrome, it started to show the following:

> [DRIVER] Chamador Kernel Herdado
>   (this is equivalent to [DRIVER] Legacy Kernel Caller)

I've tried running without success both:
`powercfg -requestsoverride Driver "Legacy Kernel Caller" System`
`powercfg -requestsoverride Driver "Chamador Kernel Herdado" System`

Two important things:
- The Kernel entry vanished after I closed Spotify
- I turned my computer on just now, so I can put it to sleep without problems even with the Kernel entry on my `-requests`, the issue seems to appear after 2 hours

**EDIT 3**:
I have reasons to believe the Kernel thing is not the issue, this forum post is similar to my problem, my computer won't shut off also, after two hours.
https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/66640-wont-enter-sleep-legacy-kernel-caller.html

**EDIT 4**:
Maybe this can be related, maybe not...
When sleeping normally (with the computer on for less than 2 hours), the disk light blinks a lot, and then it goes to sleep.
But when the sleep fails, the disk light blinks 3 or 4 times before turning off, and then the wifi light and power light stays on. That's when the computer freezes.
My HD got replaced by a SSD recently, and that's when the problems started. I'm using a Dell Inspiron 14R.

**EDIT 5**: results from running `powercfg -energy`:
http://codepen.io/carvalho23lucas/full/OpXYLq/
I've added a plugin to translate the page, you can find it in the first line

**EDIT 6**: results from running a clean `powercfg -energy`:
http://codepen.io/carvalho23lucas/full/mWEZpr/
I turned off bluetooth, closed all open programs, killed the audio process and ran the command.
Immediately after that, I tried to put the computer to sleep. Failed again.

Comment: What do you get when you run powercfg -requests in an admin command prompt?

Comment: [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
WebRTC has active PeerConnections

Comment: So you installed your display drivers and network drivers.  What about the chipset drivers, which typically, allow and prevent your machine from entering or existing (S1 through S4) power states.  Please update your question, instead of commenting, as the comment section has limited formatting options.

Comment: But I already tried letting my computer on for 2 hours without opening any program, it wouldn't sleep even so

Comment: chipset drivers up to date

Comment: @Lucas - So you have a program that is preventing it from entering that power mode.  By the sounds of it, that would be Chrome, try manually ending all Chrome processes and manually place your machine into sleep mode.

Comment: You can use `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` to identify which devices are configured to wake (or keep the system awake).

Comment: after manually terminating chrome, I've tried calling `powercfg -requests` again, and it now says "Legacy Kernel Caller"

Comment: Use Autoruns to identify and possibly disable any startup entries you do not recognize: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: You should be able to simply, issue the following command within an elevated command prompt, `Powercfg -requestsoverride Driver "Legacy Kernel Caller" System` to solve your problem. This actually isn't my [suggestion](http://superuser.com/questions/370429/legacy-kernel-caller-preventing-sleep-mode)

Comment: Done, after that, the `powercfg -requests` command still shows the Legacy Kernel Caller, is it normal? `powercfg -requestsoverride` also show it.

Comment: When you manually attempt to put your machine to sleep what happens?  If there isn't a option to that in your start menu, there is still something, blocking that capability which you need to use AutoRuns to identify.

Comment: When I manually put my machine to sleep, after letting it on after 2+ hours, the screen will turn off, but the power light and the wifi light will stay on, and then I need to forcefully turn the computer off by holding the power button

Comment: I have reasons to believe the Legacy Kernel Caller is not the issue. This forum post (unsolved) shows what is happening: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/66640-wont-enter-sleep-legacy-kernel-caller.html

Comment: is "hybrid sleep" activated on your computer?

Comment: no, hibernation is disabled as well, as I explained on the question

Comment: Can you post the output of [powercfg -energy](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/)? It's also worth a try to see if this happens after booting in Safe mode.

Comment: Sorry, got busy at work. I added the output now. I'll test the safe mode now

Comment: As much as I understood from the energy report, it's worth trying also with all possible devices disconnected, especially USB devices.

Comment: They were already disconnected, the report is complaining about the USB Hub itself.

Comment: added clean `powercfg -energy` output. I'm losing hope.

Comment: update: it does happen in safe mode. Although the Suspend option is not available, when I turn off after a few hours on, it wont turn off either.

Comment: Here's an idea, which will not harm your system: In CMD (running as admin), the following      chkdsk c: /r     this will take a while as Windows will look for errors and correct what it finds.  Your personal data and apps will not be disturbed

Comment: Please do [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html) to check system integrity. If this finds nothing, a non-destructive (but heavy) action is [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) of Windows 10 to itself which will refresh Windows components without harming your apps and data (but do all backups first anyway).

Comment: sfc /scannow didn't found anything, chkdsk didn't found anything either

Comment: 1) Do you have a secondary HDD installed? Or is it just SSD?
2) Did you try uninstalling Intel Management Engine driver and running troubleshooter for Windows update? These two things are adviced on various forums in case of power problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a long time dealing with that problem, I finnaly had some advances.
I am not sure what exactly happened, but here are two things I did:

1. I reset power settings to defaults and changed what I needed from scratch (like, sleep delay etc). Also, I set AHCI Link Power Managment to HIPM+DIPM. I am inclined to believe that this is **not** important, but I am mentioning this because I did it.
2. On threads about problems with sleep mode, I have many times seen the advice to rollback or remove Intel Managment Interface Engine driver. I didn't have the option to rollback and removal didn't do anything for me: it was just back after a reboot. So I updated the driver instead. It was not distributed through Microsoft servers for me, so I went for a [first link on google](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26135/Intel-Management-Engine-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-1-for-Intel-NUC) and installed it manually. It is now of version 11.0.5.1189 for me.

Later, after six hours of runtime, I closed the lid and my laptop went to sleep for the first time since win10 install (except sleep right after restart). I suppose second thing from the list above is what helped. (Of course, I've had hibernation, fast boot etc. disabled a long time ago.)

Comment: Sorry for taking too long, I had too little time in hands. I reseted my computer and it didn't work, but your second solution did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have also had software issues (sleep, dual-boot install failure...) on a dell computer (server) with a newly installed Corsair SSD.

These problems were not present with the original HD. And to this day the same problems persists...

Are you sure your SSD is 100% compatible with the Dell hardware (SATA controller on the motherboard ...). Have you tried contacting Dell about this issue ? Have you tried another SSD/HD ?

As far as I am concerned this is a hardware issue.

Good luck

Comment: How can I assure that it is in fact a hardware issue?

Comment: First step IMHO would to try another ssd/hd. I know it is not quite convenient but it would give you valuable info on the nature of the issue.

Comment: I don't have another ssd/hd available, the previous one got damaged...

Comment: I ran the Dell system diagnostics software and all tests passed, the ssd seems to be working properly. I'll try a clean Windows install...

Comment: A clean install could be a solution, please keep us posted. In case this doesn't work I also suggest you, since you don't have access to other harddrives, to play with the different BIOS settings related to the hard drive controller (AHCI, RAID, power saving options ...). Also, you should check if the SSD doesn't have a driver that you should install, or even better, one that is officially supported by DELL. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue, where putting the PC to sleep only turns off the displays.

In my case, there is some software prevent my PC from going to sleep. To solve this, open cmd and type in:

```
powercfg -requests
```

Under the System, there is one software process:

[image]

You can either close the software or override its power setting:

```
powercfg -requestsoverride PROCESS “myprocess.exe” SYSTEM
```

The `PROCESS` in the command corresponds to the content inside the `[]` from the command line and `SYSTEM` corresponds to the category:

[image]

Comment: ok... just realised you have checked `powercfg -request`... This is not a solution for your problem but this might solve a similar one for others, so I'll keep it.