# Why does 'Powercfg -requestsoverride Driver "Legacy Kernel Caller" System' fail to let my laptop hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Please see the screenshot beneath: my 4 inputs failed to solve the difficulty identical to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/370571/269574).  When I tried to 'Hibernate' after inputting it, my laptop still failed to hibernate.

[image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zd4qjFL9pAK1MVf9qXn7egsYYvPtZiK4)'s my [energy-report.html](https://superuser.com/questions/1342276/why-does-my-windows-10-laptop-fail-to-hibernate-sometimes#comment2010572_1342276).

[image]

[Wake Timers](https://superuser.com/q/973009/269574) have been disabled:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried `powercfg -H on` ?

Comment: Please run powercfg -energy as explained in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/) and post the result. Add also the result of the command `powercfg -requests`.

Comment: @Alex I did now, in vain.

Comment: @harrymc I did this at https://superuser.com/q/1342276/269574, but I redid it now.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Wake Timers: done. Closing Chrome doesn't help.