# Computer doesn't remain in power-off state

Tags: windows, bios, power-management

I can't hibernate my computer. After finishing hibernate and powering off, it powers on again and boot.

All options in BIOS known to me are disabled:

[image]

Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-B85M-D3H

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

Powercfg gives the following answer:

```
C:\Windows\System32>powercfg /lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 0
```

Computer wakes only from within hibernate mode. It doesn't autowake if in poweroff mode.

**UPDATE 2**

Disabling mouse wake up didn't help.

I emphasize, that I am speaking not about sleep mode, but about hibernate mode. This is different mode. When mouse wake up was on, I still was unable to turn computer on by mouse. Because in hibernate mode mouse is powered of and can't send any signals to anywhere.

**UPDATE 3**

I have set network card to this:

[image]

Previously "Only allow a magic..." checkbox was unchecked. Now my computer "survives" whole night in hibernate mode!

But when I am coming to it in the morning and touching mouse, it is immediately waking up! This is despite the fact I have disabled mouse wake up during research.

Microsoft never does what it told to :)

Comment: I'm going to assume Windows here:  Open a command prompt and run `powercfg /lastwake`.  It should spit out what woke your computer back up.  The culprits on my machine was my wireless mouse and my keyboard being able to wake the machine up.

Comment: @kazoni how can OS affect? In hibernate mode computer should be completely powered off.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT this is not me who does this operations: computer does them automatically

Comment: I had the same problem a few years ago - I believe there is an option to prevent the network card from waking the computer. After checking this option, I am now happily hibernating my PC, and I decide when to wake it back up... Try it out!

Comment: I saw you have accepted my answer. Would you mind to leave a comment to precise which part of the answer worked out?

Comment: Apparently, configuration of network card helped, but not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gigabyte UEFI seems to have an [issue](http://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/quick-guide-to-configuring-the-uefi-on-gigabytes-7-series-lga-1155-motherboards.63276/#post-402802) with Wake On Lan, which is known to cause reboots after a shutdown in some conditions. Since "hibernation" is a glorified name for "dump your RAM on the disk and shut down", you may have experienced exactly that.

Try to find an option in your UEFI settings which reads like "Wake on Lan" or "Wake on PCI" and disable it. Another thing to try is to modify your network adapter settings in Windows:

- Device manager `->` right click on your network adapter `->` Properties `->` Advanced `->` Wake on magic packet = Disabled
- Device manager `->` right click on your network adapter `->` Properties `->` Power Management `->` Allow this device to wake up the computer = Unchecked

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing similar issues and suddenly autoboots with and HP ProDesk 600 G2. After being mad trying different BIOS configs, the problem was Windows 10 "Fast Startup" option.

After unchecking it, my problem was solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

Laptops will wake-up if mouse or keyboard is pressed.

Go to Control Panel and open **MOUSE > Hardware > Properties > General > Change Settings > Power Management >** and uncheck `"Allow this device to wake up pc"`.
[image]

(do the same for Keyboard, Network Devices..... You can do it from ControlPanel or Device manager too).

## Method 2

To see the last devices, which WOKE UP computer, type this in CMD:

```
powercfg –lastwake
```

To find out which devices are enabled to wake up the PC, enter this command

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
```

If not helps, try this [Source 1](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-fix-computer-keeps-waking.htm).

(source 2: [Why does my Windows computer immediately turn back on after sleep/hibernate?](https://superuser.com/questions/113801/why-does-my-windows-computer-immediately-turn-back-on-after-sleep-hibernate))

Comment: It is PC. Why it doesn't show than mouse woke up it?

Comment: @Dims Check the same for all your network devices, WLAN, LAN, mobile. Some device in your network might send magic packets to your network device which might wake your PC.

Answer (score -1):

You could try looking in the Task Scheduler for tasks that wake the computer up to do updates, scans or maintenance routines.

Comment: How can task in task scheduler wake up powered off computer?