# Why do my machines keep turning on after going to sleep?

Tags: sleep

I have had this problem with my desktop machine for over 24 months and the only reason I put up with it is because I thought it was the motherboard being crappish. That PC was running Windows 7 and then Windows 10.

- To prove 100% it was not LAN magic packets I unplugged the Network
- I also unplugged Keyboard and Mouse to prevent wake on USB
- I turned of all BIOS related setting for wake up I could find
- Turned of all allow on wake from on Network devices in Windows

Nothing sorted the problem. Everything but power was unplugged it kept comming out of sleep. Sometimes even 5 seconds after it went to sleep. The only solution was for me to pull the power cable out every night...

Now I got rid of that machine and got a Dell Latitude and the flippen things turns on at night on its own again??!?!? 
Not only that but my wife's Acer started doing the same thing.

I seriously do not know why this started happening. For years I have used sleep mode and it worked fine now all of a sudden the machines are arising .. ehm . waking on their own the whole bloody time.

Anybody know what this is?? Maleware in my BIOS? Printer sending out magic packets? Really annoying me now ...

Comment: Have you looked at some of the answers on this question: http://superuser.com/questions/113801/why-does-my-windows-computer-immediately-turn-back-on-after-sleep-hibernate?rq=1

Comment: Ahh thanks. I found an entry in my Event Log saying it woke my machine up for a reboot :angry: and hundreds of the same.. why??

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Windows can wake it self up for whatever reason it like. It seems like it just keeps on sending wake events to reboot, as I have found out from the event log. [More info thanks to this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/113801/why-does-my-windows-computer-immediately-turn-back-on-after-sleep-hibernate?rq=1)

[image]

And hidden deep inside power options is this little basterd.

[image]

I have set it to disabled and going to go look and my wife's machine too. Looks like the cause of the problem but need to leave it a while before I can verify that.

Comment: It might be related to a rouge update that never cleared the registry keys... I remember having a similar problem

Comment: In my case: `Wake Source: Unknown`. Great...